# Como recuperar el valor de Func, Action de un Dictionary . C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Estoy haciendo un diccionario, en el cual la llave es un String y el valor podría ser un Action o Func.

```
Dictionary < string, Action<string> > DicAction;
Dictionary < string, Func<string> > DicFunc;
```

Instancio los diccionarios;

```
DicAction =  new Dictionary < string , Action<string> ();
DicFunc   =  new Dictionary < string , Func<string>();
```

Inserto al diccionario los parámetros.

```
DicAction.Add("RecuperaListaAction", data => { 

 return (data=="RESULT") ? List<Item> : null;

});

DicFunc.Add("RecuperaListaFunc", data => { 

 return (data=="RESULT") ? List<Item> : null;

});
```

## Mi pregunta es cómo recojo el valor retornado

```
var resultListAction = DicAction["RecuperaListaAction"]("RESULT");
var resultListFunc   = DicFunc["RecuperaListaFunc"]("RESULT");
```

Ya que no soy capaz de recuperar el dato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero por parte:

## 1

```
 Dictionary <string, Action<string>> DicAction;
```

Los `System.Action` no tienen tipo de retorno, solo puedes especificarles parametros pero no tipos de retornos por lo que esto es invalido:

```
DicAction.Add("RecuperaListaAction", data => { 

 return (data=="RESULT") ? List<Item> : null; // no puedes retornan en un delegado tipo System.Action
});
```

En tu caso el `Action<String>` significa que esperas un delegado que tenga un parametro de tipo `String`:

La forma valida de hacer seria:

```
 DicAction.Add("RecuperaListaAction", (parametroString) => {
                // no puedes hacer retorn...
});
```

## 2

```
Dictionary <string,Func<string>> DicFunc;
```

A diferencia de los action, los delegados `System.Func` si retornan y el tipo de retorno seria el ultimo parametro generico definido.

En tu caso `Func<String>` significa que espera un delegado que retorne `System.String` *sin parametros* pero en tu código defines que esperas un parametro y retorno por lo que es invalido:

```
DicFunc.Add("RecuperaListaFunc", data => { 
 return (data=="RESULT") ? List<Item> : null;
});
```

Para que funcione tienes que especificar otro parametro generico para acepte un parametro `string` y retorne `string` que seria:

```
   Dictionary < string, Func<string, string> > DicFunc;
```

Por lo que ahora si es valido lo que esperas.

Entonces el codigo final seria:

```
  Dictionary<string, Action<string>> DicAction;
Dictionary<string, Func<string, string>> DicFunc;

DicAction = new Dictionary<string, Action<string>> ();
DicFunc = new Dictionary<string, Func<string,string>>();

DicAction.Add("RecuperaListaAction", (str) => {

});

DicFunc.Add("RecuperaListaFunc", (str) => {

    return (str == "RESULT") ? List<T> : null;
});
```

Y se ejecuta de la siguiente manera:

```
DicAction["key"]("datos");// los actions no returnan 
String resultado = DicFunc["key"]("parametro"); // func si retornan por lo que podemos almacenar el valor de retorno
```

Comment: Oido cocina, no entendía mu bien el funcionamiento de Action y Func. Gracias.